# EXCEL: Is there a way to apply an additional formula to multiple cells with existing formulas?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm working on a spreadsheet that pulls data from other sheets and compiles it all into one place to calculate means, percentiles etc. The problem is when some of the data on the original sheets hasn't been filled in, I get errors in some of the cells which then gives errors in cells used to calculate the mean and other characters (i.e. taking the mean of a range of means). The formulas for each cell are also very different and take data from different places, not adjacent cells, so changing one cell and then copying this into other cells won't work.

I can input the "IFERROR(Cell, 0)" to eliminate this, but was wondering if there was a way to apply this to a range of cells whilst keeping the existing formulas. I can do it manually but there are over 2000 cells that this would need to be done to. I know I could also create a separate sheet but I've been told not to do this. Sorry if this is really obvious, I'm just stuck! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps edit the VBA code to check if it's empty then set to `0`? I assume the VBA code has loops and such so that you might just need to change the code on a few places to get the same effect as 2000 formulas.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a macro like this. Simply select the range of cells and run it.

```
Sub AddIfError()
    Dim rCell                 As Range
    Dim rFormulas             As Range
    Application.Screenupdating = False
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Selection.HasFormula Then Set rFormulas = Selection
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rFormulas = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

    If rFormulas Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No formulas in selection"
    Else
        For Each rCell In rFormulas
            If UCase$(Left$(rCell.Formula, 8)) <> "=IFERROR" Then
                If rCell.HasArray Then
                    rCell.CurrentArray.FormulaArray = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(rCell.FormulaArray, 2) & ","""")"
                Else
                    rCell.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & Mid$(rCell.Formula, 2) & ","""")"
                End If
            End If
        Next rCell
    End If
End Sub
```